# How do I remove the eye icon that shows visibility on login screen and reset password screen

Tags: customization, login, password, icon

I'm looking for a way to remove the eye icon that shows visibility on login screen (wp-admin and wp-login) and reset password screen (/wp-login.php?action=rp).

As you can see on the screenshot below :

Login Page :

[image]

Reset password Page :

[image]

Update : I need to remove this button not only the visibility :

[image]

Thanks in advance for your reply.

regards.

Answer (score 1):

This is one way

```
add_action('login_head', 'my_remove_eye');

function my_remove_eye() {
  echo 
    '<style>
        span.dashicons-visibility:before {
        content: "";
    }
    </style>';
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to do the same with reset password page please?

Comment: That code will remove it for both screens

Comment: it still visible on reset screen. Another thing. the zone of eye icon is still there. it's just not visible but if we click on the place the eye icon was it appear again.(that's the result with previous code on the login screen)

Comment: can't help you unless you provide a link to the site.  In my test the css loads on both pages.  To remove the eye completely you could use display:none; instead of content:"";

Comment: Can you put the code to do it please?

Comment: I'm looking for a way to remove the Button from the password field not only the visibility. I added an image to explain my need. where can I found this button on wordpress Core please?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same mechanism to enqueue some JavaScript that will actually remove the button:

```php
function remove_wp_hide_pw_button() {
?><script>
if ((document.addEventListener != null) && (document.querySelector != null)) {
    document.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        var b = document.querySelector('button.wp-hide-pw');
        if (b != null) b.remove();
    });
}
</script>
<?php
}
add_action('login_footer', 'remove_wp_hide_pw_button');
```

However the button will appear briefly then disappear, so you probably do need CSS to hide it the button or icon too.